# Integrating PayPal checkout with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I currently working on integrating PayPal express checkout for digital goods using Codeigniter. I went through PayPal wizard which creates some HTML and JavaScript for the button and also few PHP files are created. However since the file are pure PHP and neither controllers or models I am not sure how to call them. HTML code has some form action:

```
<form action='checkout.php' METHOD='POST'>
```

Now where should I put this checkout PHP in models or view and can I call it via controller using something:

```
www.myweb.com/index.php/mypalpal_controller/paypal_function
```

And inside controller function should the call go like:

```
$this->user_model->checkout;
```

And would the checkout.php require further modification so that everything is inside the model class?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be needing this : http://phpfour.com/blog/2009/02/php-payment-gateway-library-for-paypal-authorizenet-and-2checkout/ and this: http://www.amplio.ch/blog/web-development/paypal-integration-to-codeigniter/
its a good resource

Comment: second url http://www.amplio.ch/blog/web-development/paypal-integration-to-codeigniter/ is not working now.

Comment: @VipinKr.Singh see, this was answered in 2013, honestly I haven't kept a track of the changes in paypal api and sites die now and then ... and then SO provides the option to edit/add answers to questions, so for the new stuff, you could either edit or add a new answer.

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in this [CodeIgniter PayPal library](http://www.binpress.com/app/paypal-adaptive-payments-pro-payflow-codeigniter-library/140) I developed.  It ties nearly every PayPal API call available into CI in a very simple to use fashion.